# Grade of the Hom functor

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $I$ an ideal and $M, N$ finite $R$-modules. Prove that $\operatorname{grade}(I,\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N))\ge\min(2,\operatorname{grade}(I,N))$.

This question is Exercise 1.4.19 in the book of Winfried Bruns and Jürgen Herzog, *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*, Cambridge University Press, 1998.

I guess maybe Prop 1.2.9 in the book is helpful.

Comment: I think you will get more help and attention when you write something about your thoughts and attempts (and maybe also the definition of "grade" for those who haven't seen it).

Comment: Here grade has another familiar name I-depth, here is the wiki:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_(ring_theory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you observed, this is a consequence of the Depth Lemma. But first, another lemma:
$\DeclareMathOperator{grade}{grade}$
$\newcommand{Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$
$\newcommand{Ext}{\operatorname{Ext}}$
$\newcommand{coker}{\operatorname{coker}}$

**Lemma:** If $\grade(I,N) \ge 1$, then $\grade(I, \Hom_R(M,N)) \ge 1$ for any $R$-module $M$.

Proof: In general, $\grade(I, \_) \ge 1 \iff \Hom_R(R/I, \_) = 0$. By Hom-tensor adjointness, $\Hom_R(R/I, \Hom_R(M,N)) \cong \Hom_R(R/I \otimes_R M, N) \cong \Hom_R(M, \Hom(R/I, N))$.

Returning to your question: the result is clear if $\grade(I, N) = 0$, so we may assume $\grade(I,N) \ge 1$ (in fact the lemma also gives it for $\grade(I,N) = 1$, but this is merely fortunate).
Now, take a presentation of $M$,

$$0 \to K \to R^n \to M \to 0$$

Applying $\Hom_R(\_, N)$ and taking the long exact sequence yields

$$0 \to \Hom_R(M,N) \xrightarrow{\varphi} \Hom_R(R^n,N) \to \Hom_R(K,N) \to \Ext^1_R(M,N) \to 0$$

We can split this up into $2$ short exact sequences:

$$0 \to \Hom_R(M,N) \to N^n \to \coker \varphi \to 0$$
$$0 \to \coker \varphi \to \Hom_R(K,N) \to \Ext^1_R(M,N) \to 0$$

By the lemma above, $\grade(I, \Hom_R(K,N)) \ge 1$, so by the Depth Lemma for the second sequence, $\grade(I, \coker \varphi) \ge 1$, but then Depth Lemma for the first sequence gives the result (since $\grade(I,N) = \grade(I,N^n)$).

(Added for the sake of completeness: the statement of the Depth Lemma used is: if 
$$0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$$ is an exact sequence of finite modules, then $\grade(I,A) \ge \min\{\grade(I,B), \grade(I,C) + 1\}$)